# Violent Shivering in Wounded and Incapacitated Patients

Tags: pain, wound, shake-tremble-fidget

I am researching various behaviours patients exhibit when wounded, for a game project.

Apparently, when going into shock, people will sometimes shake violently? I wondered how often this happens if so, and how long this persists for (normally). I was wondering if this symptom was due to pain, or perhaps a feeling of cold?

Comment: I spent 15 years in EMS. Never saw what you're describing. Where did you hear this?

Comment: By any chance are you referring to seizures that someone might mistake for violent shivering?

Comment: @CareyGregory Checked with my source for more details. It appears that it's just that blood loss lowers your body temperature, and if you get too cold you might start shivering (which makes the bleeding worse). This, of course, won't occur in a warm environment. A friend of mine actually did suggest that seizures may be triggered by going into shock, so interesting you bring that up. That sounds like a very complicated case to treat. Thanks.